# Не учитываются числа после запятой в double

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

`100 / 3 = 33.0`, а мне нужна точность хотя бы до десятых, а лучше сотых

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте сделать сотню не целым, а плавающим: `double passed_perc = (passed * 100.) / all;`... не помогет - приведите явно операнды к `double`.

Comment: @Akina помогло, спасибо